# Delphi 10 Seattle update1 IDE high dpi support

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

Delphi 10 Seattle Update1 has this bug fix: Additional high DPI support for the IDE (see http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/44619 )
I installed it on Windows 10 64 bit. My display resolution is: 3840*2160. but the IDE does not support, Texts and objects are blurry.

---

**Edit**

After I edited that manifest and set dpi aware to true (see screen shots) it worked but not completely. Instead using this manifest, we can check "diable display scaling on high dpi setting" on application propertys. Actually that manifest do this settings not more. see my screen shots.

[image: Tool palette]

[image: Options settings]

Comment: Show code and screenshots (preferably before and afetr) please. Give more numbers (we need more screen settings).

Comment: Relevant: https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=117402

Comment: @ChrisB I guess you refer to Remys answer, but did you notice the link that OP provided. It says (third bullet concerning IDE): "Additional high DPI support for the IDE ".

Comment: Your concern has been noted by others too and there is a quality report with number RSP-11824 which claims this to be fixed in Update 1. However the comments at the end states something else, and a workaround is provided in the last comment.

Answer (score 8):

Embarcadero quality portal entry RSP-11824 states this to be fixed in Update 1. However the comments to that report says something else.

Notable comment by Nils Dzubiel with a workaround is:

> Well,  what you can do:
>
> Create a manifest: bds.exe.manifest - you find an example here.
>   http://nhdhome.nhd.com/nhddownload/SM/bds.exe.manifest
>
> Copy this file to the ..\bin\ directory.
>
> Within your registry :
>
> 1. Navigate to the following registry subkey:  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > Microsoft > Windows > CurrentVersion > SideBySide
>
>    2. Rightclick,  select NEW > DWORD (32 bit) Value
>    3. Type PreferExternalManifest, and then press ENTER.
>    4. Right click PreferExternalManifest, and then click Modify.
>    5. Enter Value Data 1 and select Decimal.
>    6. Click OK. Exit Registry Editor.
>
> Start Deplhi and be happy.
>
> Nils

I have not tested this myself.

Comment: Well done, I'm glad someone has answered this, so +1 and I'm also +1ing the q, because despite the absence of screen shot, I don't think it deserves -4.

Comment: Thanks @MartynA I agree with you about the q

Comment: I tested it, not works. Is there other way to fix this bug?

Comment: @saeid2014 Not that I know of, sorry. One of the comments (dated 1. dec. 2015) to the RSP said: "This feature will be implemented in our next release, sorry for the inconveniences". Since Update 1 was published on 19th Nov., the statement means next release after update 1.

Comment: @saeid2014 Could you please take a small snapshot and add to your question? With small I mean just enough to show the problem (and not the whole screen). Also, was there any change at all with the workaround from Nils Dzubiel?

Comment: @TomBrunberg Yes of course, Thank you for your help.

Comment: http://www.4shared.com/download/z4Pr4zEcba/delphi10_3.jpg?sbsr=45ddde613d71e319ffae9f903755ad6496a&lgfp=3000      http://www.4shared.com/download/EiMJ64YYce/delphi10_4.jpg?sbsr=6059bdcc5d3be7c9ac8cc3343fc34bb496a&lgfp=3000     http://www.4shared.com/download/zRxsmLE3ce/delphi10_5.jpg?sbsr=23850de449b19309600f66bedee19aec96a&lgfp=3000       http://www.4shared.com/download/oQZkkS8Mba/delphi10_6.jpg?sbsr=0fbee25ce95f7ed00ca63f10e3bd02d796a&lgfp=3000

Comment: @TomBrunberg Yes of course, Thank you for your help. after I edited that manifest and set dpi aware to true (see screen shots) it worked but not completely. Instead using this manifest, we can check "diable display scaling on high dpi setting" on application propertys. Actually that manifest do this settings not more. see my screen shots.